# sufficient statistics that are irrelevant

Tags: st.statistics, it.information-theory, estimation-theory

I'm designing a lecture on hypothesis testing and want to do an example on a certain matter, but I cannot come up with a good one.

If we should decide upon $H_0$ or $H_1$ given observed data sets ${\bf x}_1$ and ${\bf x}_2$, then we have
\begin{equation} \frac{p( {\bf x}_1,{\bf x}_2;H_1)}{p( {\bf x}_1,{\bf x}_2;H_0)}=\frac{p( {\bf x}_2|{\bf x}_1;H_1)p({\bf x}_1;H_1)}{p( {\bf x}_2|{\bf x}_1;H_0)p({\bf x}_1;H_0)}.\end{equation}
If we now have $p( {\bf x}_2|{\bf x}_1;H_1)=p( {\bf x}_2|{\bf x}_1;H_0)$, then it follows that ${\bf x}_2$ is irrelevant.

Now suppose that have a set of sufficient statistics, so that if $H_0$ and $H_1$ are to choose between to parameter settings $\theta = \theta_0$ or $\theta = \theta_1$, then we can write (for two statistics)
$$p( {\bf x};\theta)=g(T_1({\bf x}),T_2({\bf x});\theta)h({\bf x})$$ for some functions $g()$ and $h()$.

I would now like to find a (fun and) non-trivial example for a case similar to the first one, but where I replace ${\bf x}_1$ and ${\bf x}_2$ with $T_1({\bf x})$ and $T_2({\bf x})$.

Any good examples out there?

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you intend something like this. Suppose you want an test of the null hypothesis that two normally distributed random variables have the same variance.  The sample mean and sample variance together are sufficient statistics for a sample from a normally distributed random variable; but an $F$-test only depends on the ratio of sample variances, so the sample means are in a sense irrelevant.